# WebPage Content is displayed in a List format

Tags: html, css, elgg

I am very new to Elgg development and have currently just started out in testing and modifying the contents within Elgg. However at this point, I am perplexed in the sense that the content displayed within the Elgg page is in ListView instead of the normal webView that you would see for e.g facebook display page. Hence, Just imagine the facebook header is in listview and all the other options are in listview. That is the issue that I am facing now.

The content as shown in the diagram below:

[image: Web Content shown in List Form]

Therefore, does anyone have any idea in which directory I should look in to rectify the ListView display issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are some possible reason of your problem :

- your server/hosting is not matching with elgg's requirement, or
- .htaccess restriction of your provider (for apache), or
- etc ..

See for more detail : http://learn.elgg.org/en/1.11/intro/install.html